# Anti-concentration inequality for Gaussian random vector

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, inequalities, gaussian

I am trying to obtain an explicit expression for $C$ in terms of $b$ in the following inequality.

> Suppose that $Y$ is a centred Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^p$ such that $\operatorname EY_j^2\ge b$ for all $j=1,\ldots,p$ and some constant $b>0$. Then for every $y\in\mathbb R^p$ and $a>0$,
>   \begin{equation}\label{in}\tag{#}
> P(Y\le y+a)-P(Y\le y)\le Ca\sqrt{\log p},
> \end{equation}
>   where $C$ is a constant depending only on $b$.

A short proof of this inequality is given [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3661.pdf) (see Lemma A.1 on page 15), but I suspect that there might be some gaps in the proof. I would be very interested if someone could provide a reference for an alternative proof of such an inequality.

The short proof is based on the inequality
\begin{equation}\label{ineq}\tag{*}
 \Gamma(K)=\liminf_{\delta\to0}\frac{P(Z\in K^\delta\setminus K)}{\delta}
 \le\sqrt{2\log k}+2,
\end{equation}
where $K\subset\mathbb R^p$ is an intersection of $k$ half-spaces, $K^\delta=\{x\in\mathbb R^p:d(x,K)\le\delta\}$ and $Z$ is the standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^p$.

It seems that the idea of the proof is to use the following bound
$$
P(Y\le y+a)-P(Y\le y)\le P(Z\in K^\delta)-P(Z\in K)
$$
and then use \eqref{ineq}. However, I do not understand how they use \eqref{ineq}.

1. We have that $P(Y\le y)=P(Z\in K)$, where $K$ is an intersection of $p$ halfspaces. However, if we want to have $P(Y\le y+a)\le P(Z\in K^{\delta})$, $\delta$ cannot be smaller than $p^{1/2}a/b^{1/2}$ since the intersection of half-spaces has sharp corners while $K^\delta$ has round corners (it is a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $K$). If $\delta=p^{1/2}a/b^{1/2}$, then $C$ depends also on $p$, but they claim that $C$ only depends on $b$ so something is missing here.
2. It seems that they use \eqref{ineq} for each $\delta>0$, but the inequality is only true for $\liminf_{\delta\to0}$. I think we can only expect that \eqref{ineq} holds for $\delta<\delta_0$ for each $\delta_0>0$, but then $C$ depends on $\delta_0$.

Any help is much appreciated!